# How is substitution in type theory the composition of classifying morphisms in category theory?

Tags: type-theory, dependent-types, category-theory

In [the article at nlab about relation between category theory and type theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relation+between+type+theory+and+category+theory), it is said that *substitution* in type theory is the same as *composition of classifying morphisms* in category theory.

Can you please explain why that is so for a newbie? And ellaborating on what exactly a classifying morphism is?!

Comment: It isn't. Substitution of a term into a term is just composition of morphisms, while substutution of a term into a type is pullback (or its analogue if we're working in a general fibration).

Comment: @Andrej So you mean what it says on nLab is wrong? Or there is something I misunderstood?

Comment: I just wouldn't worry too much about that particular bit. It can probably be interpreted in a sensible way, but you shouldn't get hung up on little details, such as an entry in a table on a wiki.

Comment: @Andrej Thanks a lot for the hint. What I am mainly concerned about is that what causes, mandates, demands different $\beta$reduction steps to be equivalent in the language of category theory? Or if out another way, what does category theory have to say about $\beta$-equivalence?

Comment: There's [an old paper by Robert Seely](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/rags/WkAdj/LICS.pdf) in which he relates $\beta$-equivalences to 2-cells in a 2-category. This was a starting point for much further work, so if you look up who references that paper, you'll find a lot has been said about the question that interests you.